# phpbb users table entries deletion and its effects. what are all the clean up work before deleting an user

Tags: phpbb

I am writing a window program which will run from the system tray.
which will ping my phpbb board site to fetch new users registration information.
So with the result i can check whether the user is spam user or not.

if i feel it is a spam user then i will delete that entry from the users table.

before deleting the users table what are all the other table that i should delete.

so that there will not be any unlinked references which will then in due course of time gets numerous and waste of disk space.

so i want to know what i should do before deleting an user so that all his other activities should be cleaned off before i deleting a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you review the [phpBB Database Schema](http://wiki.phpbb.com/Tables) for tables which reference a `user_id`, you should be able to determine which tables to purge with a `DELETE FROM ... WHERE user_id = #`

Note that there are established [phpBB spam prevention tools](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=1861645) which could save you the time (and headaches) of manually reviewing every new registration.

Comment: yes... i have added keycaptcha and using cloudflare... just recently... let me see how they are going to prevent.... the problem with keycaptcha was when submitting their code i get 406 so not yet activated... then i have planned to use questionnaire or maths.

Comment: yes. and there were two tables which had references to user_id as session_user_id... anyway... it should be working...